# ResourceID in Spring Security 5.7x versions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, microservices, java-17, resource-id

I have a backend developed using micro service architecture which used Spring Security older version where we can use `@EnableResourceServer`, `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` and

```java
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
    config.resourceId(resourceId);
}
```

As you all know these features have been deprecated in later versions (5.7.x) and resource id feature is kind of important when it comes to micro services.

I am in a process of upgrading services with later versions. However I was unable to find exact solution to replace above. Can anyone guide me for new way of doing this or any other way to do this?

Technologies: Java 17, Spring Boot 5.7.2, Spring Security 5.7.2

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide#unported-features

Comment: @dur I already went through this. there are guidelines for resource server. but nothing for resource id. Thanks!

Comment: The last sentence is all about the resource id.